# DHCP on Centos7 error

Tags: centos

I was looking my dhcp log and found a few errors.
No idea what are those.

Any chance someone knows ?
Feb  9 15:55:05 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.0.0.13 via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:05 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.0.0.13 (6c:f0:49:f8:e6:f4) via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:05 cyberzen dhcpd: send_packet: Operation not permitted
Feb  9 15:55:05 cyberzen dhcpd: dhcp.c:1387: Failed to send 313 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Feb  9 15:55:06 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040506.860833] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:07 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.16 from 50:e5:49:f6:2b:1e (08194D-CYBERZEN) via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:07 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.16 to 50:e5:49:f6:2b:1e (08194D-CYBERZEN) via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:07 cyberzen dhcpd: send_packet: Operation not permitted
Feb  9 15:55:07 cyberzen dhcpd: dhcp.c:3319: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Feb  9 15:55:08 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.0.0.13 via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:08 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.0.0.13 (6c:f0:49:f8:e6:f4) via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:08 cyberzen dhcpd: send_packet: Operation not permitted
Feb  9 15:55:08 cyberzen dhcpd: dhcp.c:1387: Failed to send 313 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Feb  9 15:55:10 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040510.857309] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:14 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040514.861433] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:15 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.16 from 50:e5:49:f6:2b:1e (08194D-CYBERZEN) via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:15 cyberzen dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.16 to 50:e5:49:f6:2b:1e (08194D-CYBERZEN) via eno33557248
Feb  9 15:55:15 cyberzen dhcpd: send_packet: Operation not permitted
Feb  9 15:55:15 cyberzen dhcpd: dhcp.c:3319: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Feb  9 15:55:18 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040518.861652] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:22 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040522.860815] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:26 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040526.860962] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:30 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040530.861108] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.
Feb  9 15:55:34 cyberzen NetworkManager[692]:  [1455040534.861243] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:251] send_rs(): (eno33557248): cannot send router solicitation: -99.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions error when `dhcpd` accesses the network interface. Which user is the server running as?

Did you start the server with `systemctl start dhcpd`?

You can check which user it is running as with the command `ps aux|grep dhcpd`.

On my machine it gives:

`dhcpd    11205  0.0  0.8  25024 16560 ?        Ss   10:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -user dhcpd -group dhcpd --no-pid`

Which means that the server is running as the dhcpd user.

`cat /etc/passwd|grep dhcpd` gives me:

`dhcpd:x:177:177:DHCP server:/:/sbin/nologin`

P.S: you can format your log output using backticks to make it more readable.